# Выдает ошибку, как исправить

Tags: php

```
<?php>
   $res = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_2")
   $row = mysql_fetch_row($res);
   $total = $row[0];
   echo $total;
   ?>
```

Выдает ошибку:Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$row' (T_VARIABLE) in....

Подскажите как решить проблему.

Answer (score 2):

Первая строка: было `<?php>` надо: `<?php`

Вторая строка: пропустил точку с запятой - `$res = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_2");`

Comment: Все равно выдает ошибку, но другую.